# How do I get specfic cell values from Google Sheets using Python for a discord bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, google-docs-api

I am setting up a new bot, which is send message based on the requested parameters, which are stored on a Google Doc sheet.

For example if I command:
   `&bot maximum bpd` or `&bot minimum bpd`

It should be able to get the value from a specified cell, like : `45.6` or `34.3` from different specific cells. How do I go about this?

I have already set up the basic functioning of the bot, it can respond to basic queries, like giving urls and responses.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
prefix = "&"


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("xyz")
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("der"))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello. How may I serve you?')

    if message.content.startswith('link') or message.content.startswith('link2'):
        await message.channel.send('url_here')


client.run('Token')
```